# How to convert many url parameters into object as argument of @Controller method?

Tags: http, spring-mvc

I need to pass many request params to `@Controller`.

So I want all these params to be wrapped into object which is provided as argument of `@Controller` by spring mvc. 
I also want to use `@Valid` annotation on this argument.

This is the same as `@RequestBody` with POST http method.

But I need object like `@RequestBody` with GET http method.

How to put all request params into single object which is provided as argument in `@Controller` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@RequestBody` as well, but you also have `@ModelAttribute` annotation to map parameters into a bean's properties.

Comment: Can I use `@RequestBody` with `RequestMethod.GET` ?

Comment: You can, provided the parameters are whithin the request. You can use `@ModelAttribute` to map those parameters in the URL into a bean's properties as well (this is what I usually do).  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/